# Can an sql query ever return a different result than the relational algebra version?

Tags: sql

Can an sql query ever return a different result than the relational algebra version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In relational algebra, duplicates are removed. SQL can return duplicate rows, you have to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to force it to remove duplicates.

There are probably other cases, but this is the simplest example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For example, phenomena caused by interactions between insufficiently isolated transactions: e.g. dirty read, nonrepeatable read, and/or phantom read.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html